# Looking for the 100 first decimal digits of $e$ (mathematical constant)

Tags: exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

**What i have searched !**

[value till 50 precision can be calculated from here](http://keisan.casio.com/calculator)

> Ans is:   2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470937

I need till 100 precision and this should be exact !

Comment: type `N[e,100]` to wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 100 digits of $e$ are:

$2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535 
945713821785251664274$

From: http://www.miniwebtool.com/first-n-digits-of-e/?number=100

Just Google '100 digits of e' and it should come up

Answer (score 1):

There are many places you can google. For example: http://www.numberworld.org/digits/E/

Comment: @Andrie where is my ans in the link

Comment: In the "Selected Digits:" section, there are many digits, including the first 100, both decimal and hexadecimal. $$7182818284 5904523536 0287471352 6624977572 4709369995 : 50\\
9574966967 6277240766 3035354759 4571382178 5251664274 : 100$$ The $:50$ means that those are the first 50 digits, $:100$ are digits from 51 to 100

Answer (score 1):

From WolframAlpha (click on "More digits") 
http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%281%29&x=0&y=0

[image]